# Como redirecionar o site quando for um mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

Tenho o seguinte código que deveria funcionar, mas no celular não funciona no navegador chrome:

```
var permitir_mobile = true;
var mobileUrl = 'http://m.meusitemobile.com.br';

$(document).ready(function() {
    var e = window;
    redirectIfWidthLargeSize(e);
    $(e).resize(function() {
        redirectIfWidthLargeSize(e);
    });

});

function redirectIfWidthLargeSize(e) {
    if ($(e).width() < 1024 && permitir_mobile == true) {
            e.location.href = mobileUrl;
    }
    if ($(e).width() < 1024) {

        var el = '<li class="mob-url"><a href="' + mobileUrl + '">Versão Mobile</a></li>';

        if ($('#menu_horizontal_base ul li.mob-url').length != 1) {
            $('#menu_horizontal_base ul li:last').before(el);
            $('footer nav ul li a').css('padding','30px 8px');
        } else {
            $('#menu_horizontal_base ul li.mob-url').remove();
        }
    }
};
```

Interessante é que se fizer isso na tela do meu celular, ele mostra **980**, ou seja, é menor que **1024**:

```
$(function() {
   document.write('<p style="font-size:120px">'+$(window).height()+'</p>');
});
```

Então ele deveria redirecionar na condição abaixo, mas não é o que está acontecendo:

```
 if ($(e).width() < 1024 && permitir_mobile == true) {
     e.location.href = mobileUrl;
 }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tens duas opções:

- detetar se é mobile ou não
- detetar a largura do ecrã com `.matchMedia`

A primeira é simples, basta detectar se no UserAgent existe a string `Mobi`:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Mobi/)) location.href = ...
```

ou usando tecnologia que só há nos mobiles/pads:

```
if(typeof window.orientation !== 'undefined') location.href = ...
```

Se optares por verificar a largura do ecrã podes fazer assim:

```
var mobile = window.matchMedia("only screen and (max-width: 760px)");
if (mobile.matches) location.href = ...
```

Comment: Interessante, vou testar aqui essa última...

Comment: Vou colocar para testar qualquer um dos casos, tem que rolar.

Comment: Descobri que o problema que estou tendo é mais embaixo, vou ter que dar mais uma estudada no meu código.

Answer (score 2):

Já fiz isso e consegui da seguinte forma, isto pode ficar logo na `<head>` para não perder tempo a processar outras coisas antes visto que vai (pode) ser redirecionado, nem precisa do jquery:

```
redi_width = 1024;
if(window.innerWidth < redi_width) {
    window.location.replace(mobileUrl);
}

window.onresize = function() {
    if(window.innerWidth < redi_width) {
        window.location.replace(mobileUrl);
    }
};
```

Comment: Mas eu gostaria de entender por que o meu não está funcionando? Sabe me dizer?

Comment: qual a diferença de `window.innerWidth` e `window.width` ?

Comment: @IvanFerrer `window.width()` não existe em javascript nativo: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_innerheight.asp

Comment: @IvanFerrer Testei o seu codigo e no meu funciona

Comment: Olá @Miguel, tem o `screen.width`, é verdade, me confundi.

Comment: Exato, pode usar isso se quiser @IvanFerrer

Comment: Estive a pesquisar @IvanFerrer, ao que parece `screen.width()` dá-nos o comprimento do monitor, não da janela do browser (navegador): https://helpx.adobe.com/analytics/kb/comparing-browser-width-height-and-resolution.html ... http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_screen_width.asp

Comment: Só acrescentando que `window.matchMedia(mediaQueryString)` só funciona no IE a partir da versão 10.

Answer (score 1):

Baseado na resposta do Sergio, vou publicar aqui como eu consegui resolver o problema:

```
 function redirectIfWidthLargeSize(e) {
    var w = $(e).width();
var mobile = e.matchMedia("only screen and (max-width: 1024px)");
    if (typeof e.orientation !== 'undefined' && mobile.matches && navigator.userAgent.match(/Mobi/) && origin != 'web') {
        e.location.href = mobileUrl;
    }
};
```

Usei isso para testar e deu certo:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    var origin = 'mobile'; // quando for 'web' não irá redirecionar 
    var redirect = 'não', directUrl, e = window;
    var mobile = e.matchMedia("only screen and (max-width: 1024px)");
    if (mobile.matches && (navigator.userAgent.match(/Mobi/) ||
        typeof e.orientation !== 'undefined') && origin != 'web') {
        redirect = 'sim';
    } else {
        origin = 'web';
    }

    if (e.location.search) {
       directUrl = e.location.search.replace('?','');
    }

    var redirected = (directUrl == 'mobile') ? true : false;

    if (redirect == 'sim' && !redirected) {
       e.location.href='?mobile';  
    }

    var redirecionou = (directUrl) ? 'sim' : 'não';
    $('#teste').html('largura tela: ' + $(e).width() +
                 ' redirecionará: ' 
                 + redirect + 
                 ' - versão: '
                 + origin + 
                 ' - redirecionou: ' 
                 + redirecionou +
                 ' - url de redirecionamento: ' + directUrl);
});
</script>
<div id="teste" style="font-size:45%;"></div>
```

Porém outro problema que persistia, que impedia que o script executasse, e parava o redirecionamento, era o `viewport` que não estava configurado corretamente para versões mobile, gerando um erro do tipo `warning`, como resolvi o problema:

```
 <?php if ($this->device == true || $origin == 'web'): ?>
     <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=0.333" />
 <?php else: ?>
     <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=0.5, maximum-scale=1" />
<?php endif; ?>
```